# Showing the user a random string and comparing to user's choice to the right answer

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to make a "Who wants to be a millionaire" game.

I have 15txt's representing the levels,  and on each level I have 3 questions, ex:

`Qual e a capital do Brasil? || Rio de Janeiro || Brasilia || Sao Paulo || Curitibia || Brasilia ||`
`Quantas sao as Tartarugas Ninja? || Quatro || Tres || Cinco || Duas || Quatro ||`
`Como se chama o estadio do Sporting Clube Portugal? || Sporting Arena || Esperanca XXI || Alvalade XXI || Leao XXI || Alvalade XXI ||`

Sorry, it's in portuguese.

What I have till now:

`string[][] pergresp = File.ReadLines("l1.txt").Select(s => s.Split('|')).ToArray();`
Which puts the questions on [0][0], [1][0], [2][0]. 
The answers are on [0][1], [0][2], [0][3], [0][4] and the correct answer in on [0][5].

How do I show a random question to the user one of three, and how do I compare the user's choice to the correct one?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you make things easier on yourself and create question objects with a question, the answers and a correct answer as properties?

Answer (score 3):

Create class which will represent question entity

```
public class Question
{
    public string What { get; set; }
    public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    public string Correct { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect(string answer)
    {
        if (answer.Equals(Correct, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And parse questions from your file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var quest = File.ReadLines("l1.txt").Select(ProcessLine).ToArray();
        var rnd = new Random();            
        int questionNum = rnd.Next(0, quest.Length - 1);
        Question question = quest[questionNum];
        Console.WriteLine(quest[questionNum].What);

        // Get the user input
        //if(question.IsCorrect(userAnswer))
        //    Console.WriteLine("Win");
        //else
        //    Console.WriteLine("Try again");
    }

    private static Question ProcessLine(string s)
    {
        var tokens = s.Split('|');

        if (tokens.Length <= 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid question");

        return new Question()
        {
            What = tokens[0],
            Answers = tokens.Skip(1).Take(tokens.Length - 2).ToArray(),
            Correct = tokens[tokens.Length - 1]
        };
    }
}
```

You should get the idea what bump had in mind. Also there will be some bugs in code so debug them.

Comment: I like OOP approach. Consider also to use something like `IsCorrect(string answer)` instead of `CheckAnswer(string answer)` - that better describes intention